# CSS: image changes on hoverp

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my code i have card with background image that i'm trying to hover over it to display another card layer with image transparent to show inner card layer as shown in attached images below, my problem is i'm not able to figure out the transparent image in card.. i tried to add a real transparent image but it didn't work, is there a way to acheive the same in below image?
thanks in advance

```html
<div class="card Fast-Growing ">
    <img class="card-img-top icon" src="assets/images/recons.png" loading="lazy">
    <div class="row-hr">

        <hr class="dot-hr">
        <hr>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class="card-title">Reconstructing The Business</h6>

    </div>
    <div class="card Fast-Growing-hovered ">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">Reconstructing The Business</h6>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: before hover]

[image: after hover]

Comment: First, you need to identify the element that needs to disappear on hover. I'm assuming it's the `<img class="card-img-top icon" src="assets/images/recons.png" loading="lazy">`, correct?

Comment: yes exactly ...

Comment: I feel like the image you put use js afterwards. It it possible to use css only to acheieve it but always better use js event mouseover

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS properties `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none`

Comment: thank you, but my problem is in HTMl it self ... i'm trying to add a card with image transparent over the small icon image so in hover all border color  will turn to red as shown in images above but it's not working with me

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS to make the `<img />` tag disappear on hover like so. Modify the transition duration as you like but this is the idea.

```css
.card-img-top {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but my problem is in HTMl it self ... i'm trying to add a card with image transparent over the small icon image so in hover all border color  will turn to red as shown in images above but it's not working with me

Comment: If you need detailed guidance for styling, you should also include the current CSS in your original question so we know where to go from there. Or you can make a jsfiddle/codepen

Comment: i didn't write CSS yet cuz my problem in html it self ... check images i provided in question above .. the second image result after hover over the small icon in first image and thats my problem i couldn't figure out the way to build the html